# Passing data with port.on in Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a simple add-on that finds numbers on a page and displays them in html panel in the add-on.

How do you access the data and assign the variables [with port.on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html)?

myMessagePayload contains `"4000, 800"` that are sent from the main.js file.

```
//main.js
var tag = ".first, .second";
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  //include: "*.example.com",
  include: "http://example.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("element-getter.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit("getElements", tag);
    worker.port.on("gotElement", function(elementContent) {
      pcPanel.port.emit("message",elementContent);
    });
  }
});

// element-getter.js
self.port.on("getElements", function(tag) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(tag);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    self.port.emit("gotElement", elements[i].innerHTML);
  }
});


// display.html
addon.port.on("message", function handleMyMessage(myMessagePayload) {
  var firstNumber = parseInt(myMessagePayload[0]);
  var secondNumber = parseInt(myMessagePayload[1]); 
}

console.log(myMessagePayload); 
//info: addon: 4000
//info: addon: 800


console.log(myMessagePayload[0]) //returns 4
console.log(myMessagePayload[1]) //0
console.log(myMessagePayload[2]) //0
console.log(myMessagePayload[3]) //0
```

**How do you set values received by port.on() to variables?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.port.on()` will receive objects. You may send any JSON-serializable object, e.g.

- Plain-old-data types, like numbers

  ```
  port.emit("num", 100);
  .port.on("num", function(data) { console.log(data == 100); });
  ```
- or strings, etc.

  ```
  port.emit("str", "mystring");
  .port.on("str", function(data) {
    console.log(data == "mystring");
    var anotherVariable = data; // pointless, but whatever.
  });
  ```
- or actual objects (JSON-serializable)

  ```
  port.emit("obj", {
    str: "mystring",
    num: 100,
    arr: [1,4,5],
    obj: {str: "anotherString"}
  });
  .port.on("obj", function(data) {
     console.log(data.str == "mystring");
     console.log(data.num == 100);
     console.log(data.arr[1] == 5);
     console.log(data.obj.str == "anotherString");
     var anotherVariable = data.obj.str;
  });
  ```

For more information read: [Communicating using "port"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html)

**Edit**

After you gave some actual code now, based on psychic debugging I *think* I understand your problem.

1. Transfer all elements at once. Remember: you can transfer arrays.

   ```
   self.port.on("getElements", function(tag) {
     var elements = Array.map(document.querySelectorAll(tag). function(e) e.innerHTML);
     self.port.emit("gotElements", elements);
   });
   ```
2. Just transfer the data over to the panel

   ```
   worker.port.on("gotElements", function(elements) {
     pcPanel.port.emit("message", elements);
   }
   ```
3. In the panel, you now got all matching elements in one message

   ```
   addon.port.on("message", function handleMyMessage(elements) {
     var firstNumber = parseInt(elements[0], 10);
     var secondNumber = parseInt(elements[1], 10);
     // more elements?
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: I added `vars` to the examples, although I'm not quite sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, or if it is just too obvious...

Comment: Alright, I my Magic Eight Ball tells me the newest edit will answer your "question".

Comment: I was pretty thorough when reading the documentation on MDN and this is the only example I could find that shows an example of passing and using a JSON array.